# next-auth/ next.js server-side callback create session

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

How do I create and confirm the session **in the server side callback** using Next.js and 'next-auth'?  When calling "signIn", we are limited to the client side hook calls. How do I create a session during the callback block at the server when using a custom provider extending OAuth?  Assume I've used "http://localhost:3000/api/authentication/signin" to access the configured provider and redirected to my SSO page.

I am able to create a custom provider and the SSO domain executes redirects to the callback GET on my 'pages/api/callback/custom' endpoint.  During this call, how do I assign and create the session after I've digested and fetched my token server to server.

All the "signIn" functions are done via a client side hook.  I don't see how I can tell 'next-auth' that a session exists and should be available in the server side end point.

**Wrapping the Session Provider:**

```
//_app.tsx
<SessionProvider session={session} refetchInterval={5 * 60}>
          <Provider store={reduxStore}>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </Provider>
</SessionProvider>
```

**Custom Provider:**

```
//CustomProvider.tsx
import { OAuthConfig, OAuthUserConfig } from "next-auth/providers"
export interface MyCustomProviderProfile extends Record<string, any> {
    sub: string
    nickname: string
    email: string
    picture: string
}
export interface MyCustomOAuthUserConfig<P> extends OAuthUserConfig<P> {
    applicationId: string,
}

export default function MyCustomProvider<P extends MyCustomProviderProfile>(
    options: MyCustomOAuthUserConfig<P>
): OAuthConfig<P> {
    return {
        id: `${options.id}`,
        name: "Your Custom Account",
        type: "oauth",
        authorization:
        {
            url: `${options.authorization}`,
            params: {
                client_id: `${options.clientId}`,
                app_id: `${options.applicationId}`,                
            },
        },       
        checks: ["pkce", "state"],
        idToken: true,
        profile(profile) {
            return {
                id: profile.sub,
                name: profile.nickname,
                email: profile.email,
                image: profile.picture,
            }
        },

        style: {
            logo: "/auth0.svg", //TODO: Replace with the correct graphic
            logoDark: "/auth0-dark.svg",
            bg: "#fff",
            text: "#EB5424",
            bgDark: "#EB5424",
            textDark: "#fff",
        },
        options,

    }
}
```

**Configuration**

```
//[...nextauth].tsx
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
    providers: [
      MyCustomProvider({
        id: "custom",
        applicationId: applicationIdentifier,
        clientId: clientIdentifier,
        clientSecret: 'your-client-secret',
        issuer: 'https://your-issuer.com',        
        authorization: `${rootApiServer}/_AppAuth`,    
                    
     }),     
    ],
    session: {
      strategy: "jwt",
      maxAge: 3000,
    },   
    callbacks: {
      async session({ session, token, user }) {        
        console.log('This was session called.');
        return session
      },
      async jwt({ token, account, profile }) {
        console.log('This was jwt called.');
        return token
      }
    } 
  }
  export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

**Callback:**

```
//pages/api/authentication/callback.tsx
export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {

    // Make sure that we have the code to digest.
    const code = req.query?.code as string;
    if (code == null) {
        res.status(401).json({ message: 'Not authorized' });
        return;
    }

    //Exchange the SSO code for bearer token.
    const tokenResponse = await exchangeCodeForToken(code, req);
    if (tokenResponse == null) {
        res.status(403).json({ message: 'Error authenticating user. Please try again.' });
        return;
    }

    // Use the bearer token to get the user's scope.
    const scopesResponse = await getUserScopes(tokenResponse.token);
    if (scopesResponse == null) {
        res.status(403).json({ message: 'There was an error determining the user\'s scope.' });
        return;
    }
   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I had overridden the API pathing and was expecting that I needed to create the callback to be the code digestion for OIDC.

When the provider is implemented correctly, the callback generated by 'next-auth' will handle the code digestion.